# Excel VBA: SaveCopyAs with different file extenstion

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel file with .xlsb extenstion and use its macros to generate several other Excel sheets based on the contents. The macros work in a way that they change the original Excel file and then use the `SaveCopyAs` method to save the generated Excel sheets.

The generated Excel sheets should be saved with .xlsx extension and format.

Using the [ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb178003(v=office.12).aspx) "C:\TEMP\XXXX.XLSX" method is not working for me because while it does change the extension it does NOT change the file format so when a user opens a generated Excel file he receives a warning message (something like "the file extension and format does not match"). The `SaveCopyAs` method does not have any other arguments.

How can I save the copies of my original .xlsb file with both the extension and format to be changed to .xlsx?

Note: the [Workbook.SaveAs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb214129(v=office.12).aspx) method does have a `fileformat` option, not sure if that helps / relevant.

Comment: Is there any reason why you are making a copy of your file? Could you not just create a new workbook and either write directly to the worksheet in the new workbook or copy contents in the new workbook?

Comment: There is not particular reason except that I am really a rookie in VBA. It would be perfectly feasible if once the contents are generated just create a new excel sheet, copy one of the tabs from the original file to this new one and then save the new file under the right file name. Do you think you can feed me with an example code for that?

Comment: If you can provide your code, we can help with that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the hint by Zac, in my case its a better solution to copy the tab with the relevant changes into a freshly created excel file and then save it with the new filename.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("myTab").Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="c:\temp\xyz.xlsx", FileFormat:=51
ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

This is actually a lot better solution for me as the end user really need the generated tab only and not the macros or any other data in the orginal excel file.