# Converting .xlsm file to .xls and send attachment through Outlook with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that will save a workbook temporarily, send it through Outlook as an attachment, then delete the file. Instead of having it sent as .xlsm, I want it sent as .xls. I was able to do this by doing

```
FileExtStr = ".xls"
```

but when I try to open the sent attachment, it gives me this message:

> "File format and extension of 'orders.xls' don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open it. Do you want to open it anyway?"

How do I not only change the name of the Format but convert the whole file to xls to avoid this error?

```
Sub EmailWithOutlook_workbook()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim TempFilePath As String
Dim tempFileName As String
Dim FileExtStr As String
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Dim Wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

'Make a copy of the file/Open it/Mail it/Delete it
TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
FileExtStr = ".xls"

tempFileName = File_Name_core & " " & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd h-mm-ss")

wb1.SaveCopyAs TempFilePath & tempFileName & FileExtStr

Set Wb2 = Workbooks.Open(TempFilePath & tempFileName & FileExtStr)       

Wb2.Save
Wb2.Close

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = email_to
    .CC = email_cc
    .bcc = email_bcc
    .Subject = email_subject
    .Body = email_body
    .Attachments.Add TempFilePath & tempFileName & FileExtStr
    .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

'Delete the temp file
Kill TempFilePath & tempFileName & FileExtStr

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

End Sub
```

**EDIT**: I have modified the code to

```
Sub EmailWithOutlook_workbook()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim TempFilePath As String
Dim tempFileName As String
Dim FileExtStr As String
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Dim Wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

'Make a copy of the file/Open it/Mail it/Delete it
TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
FileExtStr = "." & LCase(Right(wb1.Name, Len(wb1.Name) - InStrRev(wb1.Name, ".", , 1)))
'   tempFileName = Left(wb1.Name, Len(wb1.Name) - Len(FileExtStr)) & " " & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd h-mm-ss")
tempFileName = File_Name_core & " " & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd h-mm-ss")

'////////////MODIFIED PART/////////////
wb1.Sheets.Copy 'creates new workbook without macros"
'The New workbook copy is now the Active workbook
wb1.SaveAs TempFilePath & tempFileName, FileFormat:=51
wb1.Close
'////////////////////////////////////
Set Wb2 = Workbooks.Open(TempFilePath & tempFileName, , , FileFormat:=51)

Wb2.Save
Wb2.Close

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = email_to
    .CC = email_cc
    .bcc = email_bcc
    .Subject = email_subject
    .Body = email_body
    .Attachments.Add TempFilePath & tempFileName & FileExtStr
    .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

'Delete the temp file
Kill TempFilePath & tempFileName

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

End Sub
```

However, now this creates the problem that my workbook is renamed as what the attachment is (this is because instead of Saving a copy, I'm saving the file?). I want the workbook to have the same original name before the user runs the code...

Comment: Pretty sure you need to use `saveas(filename,56)` to get it as xls, rather than using `savecopyas()` since those file structures are different and just appending the xls extension doesn't really mean the same thing.  Very similar to [this link about saving copy as a different extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45455086/excel-vba-savecopyas-with-different-file-extenstion)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA: SaveCopyAs with different file extenstion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45455086/excel-vba-savecopyas-with-different-file-extenstion)

Comment: @Cyril Fixed it with your suggestion. Now it creates another problem; the name of the workbook changes in the original file...

Comment: Changing the extension does not convert the file format, it simply changes the extension. You'll need  to SaveAs with the proper type to actually do the conversion.

Comment: @KenWhite Please see my edit

Comment: In order to attach a file to an Outlook message, the file has to exist on disk. SaveAs creates a file on disk in the proper format, which can then be attached to an email. I'm not sure what your confusion is here; if you want to attach an .xls file to an email, the .xls file has to actually be there to attach.

Comment: @KenWhite Basically, I want the code to send the file as a new name as an attachment but when the code is done running I don't want the current workbook to have that new name, it needs to be the old one. Every time a user runs the code, a new attachment is made with a new name but once that the e-mail is sent the original file needs to remain as it was...Sorry I am new to VBA