# VbA to save a TXT formated copy of excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a macro to save data from a sheet of an excel document to a text file.

I am using the following which does produce the file I need:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="Rate File.txt", FileFormat:=xlTextPrinter
```

The problem is I want this new saved file to be independent/a new file where it is currently renaming the current excel workbook and treating the new saved file as if it's part of the workbook. So you can't open or use the text file because it says it's open in the excel workbook.

I tried the below code :

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:="Rate File.txt", FileFormat:=xlTextPrinter
```

but get an error because it will not let you format it anymore. The `savecopyas` part though is making an independent file like I want it to, but makes a file that is just jiberish and can't be used for anything.

Is there a way to save an independent copy but still have it formatted as the txt file type? Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK, `SaveCopyAs ` cannot change the format of the file, it just saves another copy in the same format. You could `SaveAs` the file as a `.txt` then close it, and reopen the `.xlsx`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45456439/11683?

Comment: Thanks for the info. Yeah I have been just closing and reopening the excel document and the end results are the same, but I'd like to find a way if at all possible to not have to do that since multiple people use the sheets and this is a  big inconvenience and prone to issues with naming and saving data on the sheet.

Comment: That advice is to copy the sheet (which creates new workbook) and saveas that copy.